# Setting a breakpoint on a shared library's decompiled exported function, and making Ghidra actually stop on that function when debugging a client code

Tags: ghidra, linux

I am very new to Ghidra, so please accept my apologies if my question sounds too simple. Despite the poor quality of the Internet in my country, I tried my best to find an answer online before asking but I could not find much.

Imagine we have a Linux shared object named `CustLib.so`, that exports one single function named `Func`.

Furthermore, imagine a program (let's call it `ClientProg`) imports `Func` from `CustLib.so` and calls it from its `main`.

What I have been trying to do with Ghidra is:

1. Load `CustLib.so` into Ghidra, Analyze it, and put a breakpoint somewhere within the decompiled code pertaining to `Func`.
2. Load `ClientProg` into Ghidra, Analyze it, and start it in the Debugger.
3. Wait until `ClientProg` calls `Func`, at which point I expect Ghidra to break on the breakpoint I had previously set at `Func`.

To my surprise, the last step above never happens. `ClientProg` runs from start to completion (in GDB IN-VM mode), without ever breaking on `Func`.

Could I ask whether I am actually missing something? Or am I expecting an unsupported functionality? Many thanks.

Comment: I don't think it will work like that. If you put a run `ClientProg` in Ghidra, only breakpoints in `ClientProg` will hit, not `CustLib.so`. Instead, you should do something like start debugging the `.so` but with the application path (not the file path) pointing to `ClientProg`, so `ClientProg` can be started and `CustLib.so` will be debugged. I don't know how to do this in Ghidra (due to my lack experiences with Ghidra), but that is how I would do in IDA

Comment: Thanks a lot! @raspiduino